# are there any open wifi access point softwares without authentication?

Tags: wireless-networking

I am planning to make a open wifi access point, so that clients can connect to my access point and it should not support suthentification.Please help me in telling some software's besides hostapd.

Comment: What's wrong with `hostapd`?

Answer (score 1):

Alex Chamberlain's answer is fine, however I suspect you are looking for more details, so I would suggest you look at this series of How To links.

Specifically Part 1 and Part 3, since you are setting up an access point rather than a bridge (which is the scope of part2).

[Setting up the Pi as a Wireless Access Point Part 1](http://sirlagz.net/2012/08/09/how-to-use-the-raspberry-pi-as-a-wireless-access-pointrouter-part-1/)

[Part 3](http://sirlagz.net/2012/08/11/how-to-use-the-raspberry-pi-as-a-wireless-access-pointrouter-part-3/)

They are well written, and easy to follow.